# Hot to get Visual Studio 2010 to ignore files with a .java extension

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a web site that includes some Java sample code.  Visual Studio insists that it is J# code and complains that it can't compile it because J# is not available.

If I exclude the files from the project then Visual Studio renames the files, breaking them.

What do I do?

Comment: Does this project have a project file?

Comment: No, there is no project file.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark them as 'content' in the csproj.  Either click on the item in solution explorer -> properties and set BuildAction to Content, or edit your csproj by hand and change

```
<Compile Include="Whatever.java" />
```

to

```
<Content Include="Whatever.java" />
```

Comment: Don't think that will work here. Based on the exclude = rename it sounds like he's using a project that doesn't have a project file.  Can happen in certain types of web sites.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I have no project file.  If I have no other choice I'll make one, but I'm hoping to avoid that.